# Is there a default ssh server or ftp server running on most linux distros?

Tags: ssh, ftp

I am quite new to using linux and I am wondering if, in most circumstances there is a default ssh and or ftp server running.

I have started a few virtual machines and I have always been able to ssh into the computer, but I am not sure if this is the case (meaning that I can expect to connect to them or do I have to install or start a program)

Comment: almost all of the Linux distros have `openssh` in default instalation and I believe most of them start it automatically, unlike the FTP, since it is not so universal and safe. By the way, ftp is not needed, since you can almost everywhere use SFTP, which is SSH subsystem.

Comment: The server editions usually start openssh by default, the clients probably (!) have it installed by not started. FTP-servers are generally not installed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to ask a question about linux distros in general, because some might... but, this is my experience with it, using primarily Ubuntu 14.04 server every day at work, setting up and configuring servers.

There's not one that comes preinstalled (unless you select it at the last point of the install process - install software), but the most popular and used ssh server/client (at least afaik) is [OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html). As for FTP, no there isn't one that's preinstalled either, but the one at that same install software menu in the installation is [`vsftpd`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd).

If you tell me what linux distro you're using, I can do a little more digging to see if one comes preinstalled on that, but from my experience, not necessarily. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am still looking into the different versions of linux and unix systems. and I am hoping that ssh and ftp are working.

Comment: Which one are you using though?

Comment: Fedora, the latest.